# Limiting results in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery, correlated-subquery

I was going trough ways to limit results in SQL and I have come across such a way:

```
SELECT name
FROM employees e
WHERE 2>=( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees e1 WHERE e1.birthdate>e.birthdate);
```

This query returns three youngest employees but I don't quite get how this query works. How come it is 2>= and not 2<=? Could anyone please shed the light on what this query does? Thank you!

Comment: There are better ways to get the three youngest employees.  Is your question about how to do this or about why the above works?  Also, what database are you using?

Comment: My question is about why this works. I use postgres

Comment: well, if your question is that how is your query working then, look at the subquery. try to evaluate it for each record and find out what it returns. You will know how it works. (it returns number of employees having birthdate greater than the birthdate of current record. then you are comparing this to a number, also try to rewrite that in this order `subquery <= 2` for better perception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand it with example data :

```
employeeId birthdate
1          12/29/2014
2          11/20/2014
3          01/01/2015
4          11/19/1991
```

now, evaluate the subquery for each :

```
employeeId birthdate   subquery result
1          12/29/2014  how many employees have birth date > 12/29/2014 = 1
2          11/20/2014  how many employees have birth date > 11/20/2014 = 2
3          01/01/2015  how many employees have birth date > 01/01/2015 = 0
4          11/19/1991  how many employees have birth date > 11/19/1991 = 3
```

now, apply the criteria `2>= subquery result`. It is certain that it will return empid 1,2,3 not 4.

Note : just for information that there are other approaches to achieve this efficiently.

Comment: You rock! I got it! Thanks! Yeah, I know that better solutions exist. But since I am still new to SQL, I am trying not to live gaps if I come across something that I don't  get. Thanks a lot, you made it very clear

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees e1 WHERE e1.birthdate>e.birthdate
```

Gives you the number of employees that are younger than the current employee.
So as long as 0, 1 or 2 people are younger than the current employee that row get's returned.

This gives you in the end the three youngest employees.
In fact it does only give you the employees with the 3 youngest birth dates (could be more than 3 employees)